# Secret Level 1 - what does this switch do?

Tags: descent-2

Trying to finally note down what all the switches do on this level.

Shooting the subject switch produces a "door opened" message but I cannot find where the door is.

None of the internet walkthroughs / playthroughs I have found show it. Nor does the Descent II Official Strategy Guide map of secret level 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm going to check the map editor to see what is tagged to that trigger, but it may take me a bit to readjust to the editor, it's been a looooooooong time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the DLE-XP Level Editor to find out what this trigger does, and it does indeed have a purpose:

[image]

This screenshot isn't totally clear because the editor is so dated, but essentially that trigger (in red and yellow) temporarily opens a door down the hallway from it (marked in green), in the opposite direction. I wouldn't recommend using the editor too much if you get stuck, only because it slightly ruins the experience, especially in the secret levels when triggers and puzzles are numerous. However, I did want to check, because there are a few useless triggers that slipped through QA :)

Comment: Confirmed, thanks! I had already held that door open with a marker when I tried the switch, which explains why I saw no effect. It's also a bit weird that they provided this switch because  you have access to the other side of the door to shoot it open.  Thanks again, I think I now know what all the switches do.

Comment: Long ago I asked a question about secret level 3 that got deleted because of inactivity. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255962/83232 If you have the rep to see the question and would like to answer it I could try to get it undeleted.

Comment: I've voted to reopen but it will need 4 more votes from other high-ranking Arqade members, but I'll keep an eye out if it does get reopened.